# what is difference between < length() and <=length()-1?

Tags: java

```
'String s=" ";'//java developer 
 for(int i=0;i<=arg0.length()-1;i++)//it's subtracts
```

i.e length()=10-1=9.?? otherwise it's index starts from 0?
  Hope u guys

Comment: Yes, pretty much anything is indexed at `0` in Java, save for SQL-related stuff.

Comment: -6? Really? I think this is quite a deep question. It would, I think, be upvoted on the C and C++ tags.

Answer (score 2):

Ostensibly nothing. But be careful:

I *never* use `<= length() - 1` since that *can* cause problems if `length()` is zero. These problems arise in languages that have *unsigned* types, and the *type* of `length()` is unsigned: `length() - 1` *could* wrap around to the largest possible value with disastrous results for your loop. In Java you will not encounter this problem even if you ever came across an object that returned length() as a `char` (which is the only unsigned type in Java) as a subsequent -1 will force a type promotion. Rest assured that `String#length` returns an `int`.

Comment: String.length() is an unsigned `int` so no type promotion.

Comment: Indeed. Made clearer.

Answer (score 2):

They both do the same.

Lets say you have an array with 10 elements.
Now you loop through it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length;++i) {}
```

The loop will go from 0 to 9, since until 10 every number is smaller than the length of the array itself.

The same goes with the other way of looping:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length -1; ++i) {}
```

This loop will also go from 0 to 9, since until 10 every number is smaller or equal to the length of the array -1.

So yeah, there is no difference, despite the time the subtraction of 1 will take, and this can be ignored.

Comment: thank you so much for Concentrate on this I got it @ZetQ

Answer (score 0):

The hardest thing to find is something which is not there.

In this case, there is no point in making the expression more complicated.  Most likely the original developer wrote `<= length()` and found this was one too many so they fixed it with `<= length()-1` without thinking about the fact it would be much simpler and more idiomatic to use `< length()`

In short, there is no point, it's needlessly complication and just wastes the time of someone trying to read it to work out there really is no point to it.

Comment: we Can't say like that  Condition checking much more important if condition satisfies then only increment takes place @Peter Lawrey I m Beginner So tat's y ?Concentrate on this..Catch your point Thanks